# AngularJS: Download Object as JSON File

Tags: angularjs, json, html, typescript

I'm creating a component in Angular, to which I pass a text in a certain format and convert it to JSON format.

So far so good. The point is that now I want to download the previously created object as a JSON file when I press a button, and as much as I have looked at it I can't find the form. Here I leave the part of the TS code where I create the object in JSON format:

```
onSubmit(){
    this.stats = this.FIFAstatsform.get('fifastats').value;
    this.stats = this.stats.replace(/\n/g, " ");
    this.statsplitted = this.stats.split(" ", 58);
    this.jsonobject = '{';
    for (let stat of this.statsplitted){
      if (this.statsplitted.indexOf(stat)%2==0){
        this.jsonobject=this.jsonobject+'"'+stat+'"'+':';
      }
      if (this.statsplitted.indexOf(stat)%2!=0 && this.statsplitted.length-1 != this.statsplitted.indexOf(stat)){
        this.jsonobject=this.jsonobject+stat+',';
      }
      if (this.statsplitted.indexOf(stat)%2!=0 && this.statsplitted.length-1 == this.statsplitted.indexOf(stat)){
        this.jsonobject=this.jsonobject+stat+'}';
      }
    }
    this.creado = true;
```

Comment: it's not really clear what you are trying to ask here.  Your question asks about a "JSON file", but the code you posted is just code showing converting an object to a JSON string, and has nothing to do with files.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make myself clear. With my code I create a JSON string object, and what I want to do is download this object as a JSON file through a button.